# Grid lines appear on my remote desktop everytime I work at home using Citrix. But not when I'm working at the office

Tags: remote-desktop, citrix

Grid lines appear on my Remote Desktop everytime I work at home. But not when I'm working at the office.

I usually use RDC in my computer at the office but when I am working at home, I connect using citrix via Google chrome or IE. Then these grid lines appear. I suspect it is because of my slow internet connection? My lowest connection is 1MB at home on a bad day, but good enough to run 3 youtube videos at the same time with no delay.

[image]

Comment: There are options that control how much of the graphics processing is done on the server vs local.   Can you tell us if when you connect you are using the "enable multiple monitors" or the "Use all monitors" option?  Try flipping that option to see if it affects this behavior.    I have seen optimizations that deal with pixel ratio and pixel color (something like 3:2:2) that produce that behavior - I presumed it had to do with HDMI signaling and my monitor - not remote desktop or graphics generation code.

Comment: I tried that already and it's still the same